# XSL for-each node comparison embedded result sets

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach

I'm trying to write an xsl to transform an input xml like this:

```
<transaction>
<message messagetype='Type1'>
 <param name='destination'>
  <value>some location</value>
 </param>
 <param name='payload'>
  <value>some message</value>
 </param>
</message>

 <embeddedTransaction>
 <message messagetype='Type1'>
  <param name='source'>
   <value>Default source</value>
  </param>
  <param name='destination'>
   <value>Default destination</value>
  </param>
  <param name='payload'>
   <value>Default payload message</value>
  </param>
  <param name='response'/>
  <param name='profile'/>  
 </message>
 </embeddedTransaction>

</transaction>
```

The above is basically a message packet, with the data in the child node `<embeddedTransaction>` defining the default values to use if a `<param>` isn't provided by the top level `<message>`

The resulting xml I'm after should look like this:

```
<transaction>
<message messagetype='Type1'>
 <param name='source'>
  <value>Default source</value>
 </param>
 <param name='destination'>
  <value>some location</value>
 </param>
 <param name='payload'>
  <value>some message</value>
 </param>
 <param name='response'/>
 <param name='profile'/> 
</message>
</transaction>
```

Note how the `<param name='source'>` is substituted by the one in the `<embeddedTransaction>` because it wasn't provided at the top level.
Same with `<param name='response'/>` and `<param name='profile'/>`.

I've been trying to loop through this using nested for-each statements but the way the structure of the xml is setup is causing me grief.
Can anybody see a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

This produces the requested result I think:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/">
 <transaction>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="transaction/embeddedTransaction/*"/>
 </transaction>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="param">
  <xsl:copy-of select="key('p',@name)[1]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:key name="p" match="param" use="@name"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```